# php multiple search values in file path

Tags: php, arrays, search

I am working on a php site that needs to search a set of files with any combination of search fields.

The possible search fields are

id, year, building, lastname, firstname, birthdate

The folder structure and file names are as such

/year/building/file.pdf

The filenames contain the data to search

id_lastname_firstname_MM_dd_yy.pdf

I have everything working on the site except this part. Originally I only had ID, year, and building and I was able to do if's to check for every possibility of combinations. Now there is way more combinations so it much more complex.

I was thinking nested if and in_array or such, but there has to be a better way. I just learning my way around php.

I would like to be able to search with any combination of fields. I can change the filenames if it helps.

I started with something like this

```
function search($transcripts, $studentid=null, $year=null, $building=null, $last=null, $first=null, $birthdate=null){
$ext = '.pdf';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../transcripts");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile()){
        $path = explode('\\',$file->getPath());
        $fname = explode('_', $file->getBasename($ext));
        if($path[1] == $year){
            if($path[2] == $building){
                if(in_array($last, $fname, true)){
                    if((in_array($first, $fname, true)){
                        if((in_array($birthdate
```

Originally I had seperate functions depending on which fields where filed in.

```
function bldStuSearch($building, $studentid, $transcripts){
$ext = '.pdf';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("../transcripts");
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
        $results = explode('\\',$file->getPath());
        //var_dump($results);
    if (($file->isFile()) && ($file->getBasename($ext)==$studentid) && ($results[2] == $building)){
        //echo substr($file->getPathname(), 27) . ": " . $file->getSize() . " B; modified " . date("Y-m-d", $file->getMTime()) . "\n";
        $results = explode('\\',$file->getPath());
        //var_dump($results);
        //$building = $results[2];
        $year = $results[1];
        //$studentid = $file->getBasename($ext);
        array_push($transcripts, array($year, $building, $studentid));
        //var_dump($transcripts);
        //$size += $file->getSize();
        //echo '<br>';
    }
}
//echo "\nTotal file size: ", $size, " bytes\n";
if (empty($transcripts))
{
    header('Location: index.php?error=2'); exit();
}

return $transcripts;
```

}

Now I am trying to have one search function to check for any combination? Any idea that would at least put in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had an idea about doing a scoring system but then dismissed it. I came back to it and found a way to make it work using a weighted scoring system.

This allows the search to be super flexible and maintain being portable, not requiring a database for the metadata and using the filename as the search data without having to search each PDF. I am using A-Pdf splitter to split the PDF into separate files and add the metadata to the filename.

I hope someone some day finds this useful for other searches. I am really happy the way this turned out.

I will post the entire code when I am done on http://github.com/friedcircuits

One thing I should change is to use named keys for the arrays.

Here is the resulting code. Right now the birthdate has to be entered as m-d-yyyy to match.

```
function search($transcripts, $studentid=null, $year=null, $building=null, $last=null, $first=null, $birthdate=null){
$ext = '.pdf';
$bldSearch = false;
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

if (($building == null) AND ($year == null)){ $searchLocation = "../transcripts";}
elseif (($year != null) AND ($building != null)){$searchLocation = "../transcripts/".$year."/".$building;}
elseif ($year != null) {$searchLocation = "../transcripts/".$year;}
elseif ($building != null) {
    $searchLocation = "../transcripts/";
    $bldSearch = true;
}
else{$searchLocation = "../transcripts";}

$dir_iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($searchLocation);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir_iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

$score = 0;

foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if ($file->isFile()){
        //Fix for slashes changing direction depending on search path
        $path = str_replace('/','\\', $file->getPath());

        $path = explode('\\',$path);
        $fname = explode('_', $file->getBasename($ext));
        //var_dump($path);
        //echo "<br>";
        //var_dump($fname);
        //echo "<br>";

        //fix for different search paths
        if($path[1] == "transcripts"){
            $pYear = $path[2];
            $pbuilding = $path[3];
        }
        else{
            $pYear = $path[1];
            $pbuilding = $path[2];
        }

        if ($bldSearch == true){
            if ($building != $pbuilding) {continue;}
        }


        //$fname[1] = @strtolower($fname[1]);
        //$fname[2] = @strtolower($fname[2]);


        if($fname[0] == $studentid){
            $yearS = $pYear;
            $buildingS = $pbuilding;
            $studentidS = $fname[0];
            $lastS = $fname[1];
            $firstS = $fname[2];
            $birthdateS = $fname[3];
            array_push($transcripts, array($yearS, $buildingS, $studentidS, $lastS, $firstS, $birthdateS));
            continue;
        }
        if($pYear == $year){
            $score += 1;
        }
        if($path[2] == $building){
            $score += 1;
        }
        if(@strpos(@strtolower($fname[1]),$last) !== false){
            $score += 3;
        }
        if(@strpos(strtolower($fname[2]), $first) !== false){
            $score += 3;
        }
        if($fname[3] == $birthdate){
            $score += 3;
        }
        //echo $score." ";
        if ($score > 2) {
            $yearS = $pYear;
            $buildingS = $pbuilding;
            $studentidS = $fname[0];
            $lastS = $fname[1];
            $firstS = $fname[2];
            $birthdateS = $fname[3];
            array_push($transcripts, array($yearS, $buildingS, $studentidS, $lastS, $firstS, $birthdateS)); 
            //var_dump($transcripts);
        }
    }
    $score = 0;
}

if (empty($transcripts))
{
    header('Location: index.php?error=2'); exit();
}


return $transcripts;}
```